# Selecting terminal elements

Tags: css, css-selectors

Is there a way to select elements that are not parents of any dom (of the type written as `<...>`)? I know that individual characters may count as dom, but ignoring that, I want to select the terminal nodes. In the following, `<div id=2>` would be such element but `<div id=1>` would not.

```
<div id=1>
  <div id=2>
    Hello World
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, this isn't possible with a CSS selector. You need to find another way around it depending on what you're trying to achieve.

For the record, the `:empty` pseudo-class won't work here because it only matches an element that doesn't have any text *or* element children, not even whitespace. Since your second-level `div` contains text, it is not `:empty`.